# SQL Server - Get Data from Previous Rows in Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT  a.Data ,
        a.DataID ,
        b.ParentDataID
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.DataID = b.ID
```

As an example, the first line of the result set would look like "a.DataID = 1, a.Data = Cat, b.ParentDataID = 0"; in the next line of the result set, "a.DataID=2, a.Data = Dog, b.ParentDataID = 1".

What I am trying to do is display a 4th column called "PreviousData" or whatever where it will be an empty string when b.ParentDataID = 0, but if b.ParentDataID has a value that equals some DataID (in this case 1), then it would look like:

a.DataID=2, a.Data = Dog, b.ParentDataID = 1, PreviousData = Cat

How would I go about doing this, if it's possible?

Comment: You can use [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is self join and CTE(Common Table Expression)

```
With MyView As ( 
        SELECT  
                 a.Data ,
                 a.DataID ,
                 b.ParentDataID 
        FROM    table1 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.DataID = b.ID 
             )

SELECT a.DataID,
       a.Data,
       b.ParentDataId,
       Parent.Data 
From MyView 
       as Parent 
       LEFT Join MyView as Child on Parent.DataId = Child.ParentDataId
```

Note: There could be some syntax errors as I dont have SQL management studio.

Comment: Thank you!  This is pretty much what I wanted.  This should do exactly what I want.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Use LEAD and LAG, here is an example:

```
SELECT
 LAG(p.FirstName) OVER (ORDER BY p.BusinessEntityID) PreviousValue,
 p.FirstName,
 LEAD(p.FirstName) OVER (ORDER BY p.BusinessEntityID) NextValue
FROM Person.Person p
```

Source:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Use LAG function:

```
select dataid, data , lag(dataid,1,0) over (order by dataid) as parentdataid,
lag(data,1,0) over (over by dataid) as parentdata
from table
```